# Can I skip one line and stop?

Tags: lldb

In gdb I have this define in order to skip one line

```
define skip
    tbreak +1
    jump +1
end
```

Can one do the same with lldb?

Answer (score 0):

lldb doesn't have a `define`. One option is creating an lldb script with the commands you want. From there, you can define an alias named `skip` that runs the commands.

For example, here's the contents of a file named `~/scripts/lldb/skip`:

```
tbreak +1
jump +1
```

To run this script, do:

```
command source ~/scripts/lldb/skip
```

To make this more convenient, you can create an alias in your `~/.lldbinit`:

```
command alias skip command source ~/scripts/lldb/skip
```

Comment: ok, thanx, but my problem is that apparently lldb does not accept the line specification "+1" relative to the "current line number".
Sometimes I keep single-stepping (next) and I know that there is a function call or something that causes problems, so I just wanto to skip the next line of code.
Of course one could provide the absolute line number (tbreak 1234 followed by jump 1234), but it's just a little less convenient.

Comment: `jump +1` does work. But if you're jumping a line like that, why do you need the `tbreak`?

Comment: 1) my version of lldb (lldb-900.0.45) gives an error on "jump +1".

Comment: 2) the reason for doing that is:
-- I've stopped at line 100 (line 100 will be executed if I do "next").
-- I want to skip statement at line 100 and resume single-stepping at line 101.
-- So I place a tmp breakpoint at line 101 and jump to it.

PS. The error I get is
(lldb) jump +1
error: invalid line offset: '+1'.

Comment: The "real" command for moving the PC is `thread jump`.  `jump` is a fancy alias.  For offset by line, try `thread jump -b 1`.  Apparently someone changed the "integer parsing" routine that `thread jump -b` uses recently so that it accepts "-N" and "N" but it no longer accepts "+N".  However, they didn't update the alias. The underlying command works still works (and N always meant forwards...) so `thread jump -b 1` should work correctly on any lldb version.  I filed a bug about this.

Comment: @Jim that works, thanks. And I don't need the tbreak, since lldb's "jump" (unlike gdb's) does not include an implicit "continue" command. Now I also understand Dave's question (why do you need the tbreak?). Fact is, in gdb jump = "jump and continue", so I assumed the same behavior in lldb.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would be more convenient - particularly when jumping source lines - to give users the chance to make sure that the jump went where they expected before continuing.  And this isn't such a common activity (since it is actually pretty dangerous) that the extra continue was likely to be a burden.